# Windows 10: Kerberos settings not found

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2016

In our company, we want to configure our Windows-based infrastructure compliant to the *IASE SCAP* specifications, e.g., the *Microsoft Windows Server 2016 STIG Benchmark*.
In this document, there is the rule that `Computer Configuration >> Policies >> Windows Settings >> Security Settings >> Account Policies >> Kerberos Policy >> Enforce user logon restrictions` should be `Enabled`.

I've searched for this settings in `Windows Server 2016`, `Windows 10 Education`, `Windows 10 Enterprise`, and `Windows 10 Pro` and it was nowhere visible ....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3bgA.png)

What do I have to activate or enable to see the `Kerberos Policies`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not seeing this policy on Windows 10, since it applies
on a Windows Server which is also a domain controller.

[STIG Viewer](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/windows_server_2012_domain_controller/2014-01-07/finding/V-2376)
says about it:

> This policy setting determines whether the Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC) validates every request for a session ticket against the user rights policy of the target computer. **The policy is enabled by default** which is the most secure setting for validating access to target resources is not circumvented.

Microsoft documentation is conflicting on this, but one possible interpretation
is that the effect of this setting is to make the DC check the AD user's
account policies such as logon hours and workstation restrictions.

I don't really know if this policy applies on a stand-alone computer,
and the fact that it is not to be found on Windows 10 may indicate
that indeed it does not apply at all.